# Store reverse of given linked list into another linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

In this problem I basically store the inverse of given linked list into another linked list.
Here is the function

```
void copy(struct node** aref,struct node** bref) {
    struct node* first = *aref;
    struct node* second = *bref;

    while(first!=NULL) {
        struct node* tmp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        tmp->data = first->data;
        tmp->next = second;
        second = tmp;

        first = first->next;
    }
}
```

This doesn't work. However, if I replace second by *bref it works.
Why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the while loop add the below code

```
while(first!=NULL)
{
    struct node* tmp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    tmp->data=first->data;
    tmp->next=second;
    second=tmp;

    first=first->next;
}
/* CHANGE HERE */
*bref = second;
```

The reason is that you will have to point "*bref" to the head of the inversed linked list.